# Why am I getting java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, jpanel

So basically, I'm trying to make a grid of 144 buttons (12x12) by making 12 rows down with 12 buttons along each row.

However, when I try to run, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at progrid.me.myname.grid.ProGrid.main(ProGrid.java:23)
```

Here's the code:

```
package progrid.me.myname.grid;

import javax.swing.*;

public class ProGrid extends JFrame {   
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(); //Create the frame
        frame.pack();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("My ProGrid remake");
        frame.setSize(300, 300);

        JPanel[] row = new JPanel[12];
    for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++){
        frame.add(row[i]);
            row[i].setBounds(0, i*25, 300, 25);
            row[i].setVisible(true);


            for(int j = 0; i < 12; i++){
                JButton[] button = new JButton[j]; //Make 12 new JButtons (button[0] - button[12]) for each row
                row[i].add(button[j]);
                button[j].setBounds(i*25, 0, 25, 25);
                button[j].setVisible(true);


            }
        }

    }

}
```

Line 23 is this:

```
frame.add(row[i]);
```

Which probably means this won't work either:

```
row[i].add(button[j]);
```

So could anyone give me a little shove in the right direction?
I'm not asking for you to dump code at me, I'm actually trying to learn. But some help would be great. Thanks!

**EDIT** Fixed the first problem, now I'm getting **java.lang.NullPointerException** on line *frame.add(row[i]);*

Comment: I think you are trying to create an empty row on i=0. Of course, when an array is empty, you cannot access index 0 since that is the first item of a non-empty array.

Comment: Learn how to debug.  You know what line the error occurs on, so all you need to do is figure out which value in the line is null.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**problem:**

```
JPanel[] row = new JPanel[i];
```

You are creating a new array of `JPanel` and `JButton` in each iteration of your loop, which results in an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` on the first iteration of your loop for `i=0` when it executes `JPanel[] row = new JPanel[0]; frames.add(row[0]);`

**solution:**

For both arrays, create only one instance of the array outside the loop, and update that instance in each iteration of the loop. Here's an example for the `JPanel` array:

```
JPanel[] row = new JPanel[12]; //Make 12 new JPanels (row[0] - row[12])
for(int i = 0; i < row.length; i++){
        frame.add(row[i]);
        row[i].setBounds(0, i*25, 300, 25);
        row[i].setVisible(true);
```

EDIT:

```
JPanel[] row = new JPanel[12];
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        row[i] = new JPanel();
        frame.add(row[i]);
        row[i].setBounds(0, i * 25, 300, 25);
        row[i].setVisible(true);

        JButton[] button = new JButton[12];
        for (int j = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            button[j] = new JButton();
            row[i].add(button[j]);
            button[j].setBounds(i * 25, 0, 25, 25);
            button[j].setVisible(true);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, I'm not sure why I missed that.

But now, I'm getting a NullPointerException on the line **frame.add(row[i]);**, not really sure what to do about that.

Comment: @user143134 post the updated code you have on your post.

Comment: @user143134 instantaite your array of Jpanel first before using it. see EDIT above.

Answer (score 0):

Row[0] to row[12] will create 13 rows. Make it row[11]